# Undefined anonymous function when declaring more than one function with javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I'm new to JS and trying to use anonymous functions. I have two simple anonymous functions that work perfectly by themselves, but as soon as I put them both in the script I get the "ReferenceError: checkAnswer_js is not defined" message. Why does this happen?

So basically I have an input and three buttons. The first button checks if the input value matches with a set value, and if it matches it enables the second button to send the input value. The last button acts as a link to another page:

```js
function checkAnswer_js() {
    var formulaAlpha = "5 + 5";//TEST
    var x = eval(formulaAlpha);
    if (document.getElementById('answer').value == x) {
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = false;
    } else document.getElementById('send').disabled = true;
}
function index_js() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to return to index?')) {window.location.href = 'index.html';}
}
```

```html
<div id="expresionfinal">5 + 5?</div>
<form name="lastform" method="POST" action="formulariofinal.php" accept-charset="utf-8" id="finalform" onsubmit="confirm('Are you sure you want to submit the answer?');">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="sent-answer" required id="answer" onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" onclick="checkAnswer_js();">Check answer</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="send" disabled>Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>

<div>
  <button onclick="index_js()">Return to index</button>
</div>
```

I get the errors when I click the buttons.

Edit: Corrected the syntax issue. It seems that the code is working perfectly fine here. But in my xampp server it stills gives me the error. My code is larger in there, but I wanted to simplify the question. Is it possible that a syntax error somewhere prevents the functions from being properly defined?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I cannot reproduce the error message though, you are not trying to reference a `function1` anywhere.

Comment: There is however a syntax error in your `index_js` function that prevented the functions from being declared. Omit the `return` keyword and the semicolon (and the unnecessary `== true` comparison) from the `if` condition.

Comment: "*Is it possible that a syntax error somewhere prevents the functions from being properly defined?*" - yes. You should see that syntax error on the console as well, though.